# How to detect if a button is collpased or not in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following button:

```
 <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon js-user-btn is-collapsed" data-quoteid="@user.UserId">
       <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
</button>
```

And I have a click event on that button:

```
  $('.js-user-btn').click(function() {

  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@(Url.Action("GetUserDetails", "User"))",
            data: {
                "user": id,
                "language": "en-GB"
            },
            success: function (data) {    // I want to trigger the an ajax function here, on the first click of the button. 

On the second the click of the button, the ajax should not be triggered. }
```

I want to trigger the an ajax function here, on the first click of the button.

On the second the click of the button, the ajax should not be triggered.

Comment: This will do exactly what you need - https://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Just ask `if( $(this).hasClass('is-collapsed') )`

Comment: @Roy it returns true every time

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Would you like to convert your comment to an answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a method for exactly this:

https://api.jquery.com/one/

From the docs:

> Description: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

In your case:

```
$('.js-user-btn').one('click', function() {...
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by checking the elements class whether that is having `is-collapsed` in jQuery. For your reference,
[Goto with this link](http://javascript-html-5.blogspot.in)

```js
if($('.is-collapsed').length > 0){
                alert('1');
            }
            /************* OR ***************/
            if( $(this).hasClass('is-collapsed') ){
                alert('2')
            }
```

This returns `true` or `false` for to know whether the class is present in that element.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var firstClick = true;
$('.js-user-btn').click(function() {
   if(firstClick ){
     firstClick = false;
     //send Ajax ...
   }else{
     // other code second click ...
   }
});
```